# how to write c program that calculates ln(1-x)

Tags: c, algorithm, codeblocks

[image]

C program  that calculates ln(1-x) please i wanna know why it does not work this is what i try help me!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n, i, a, j;
    float x, ln, s;

    printf("entrer la valeur de x=");
    scanf("%f",&x);
    printf("entrer la valeur de n=");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    ln = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        s = 1;
        a = 1;
        for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            s = x * s;
        }
        ln = (ln + s) / a;
        ln = ln * (1 - x);
    }

    print f("ln (1-x)= %f", ln);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Before going further, I suggest you never use `float` unless you have a compelling reason why you can't use the 'natural' type `double`.

Comment: @WeatherVane okay what next ?

Comment: "It does not work" isn't very explanatory? What doesn't work? What values did you enter, what do you expect, and what was the result?

Comment: Your code now having been formatted for legibility, it is now a lot easier to notice that `print f("ln (1-x)= %f", ln);` has a misplaced space character.  `print f` should be `printf`, without any space.

Comment: It's possible that your `ln = (ln + s) / a; ln = ln * (1 - x);` is algebraically correct for the formula given, but that's not obvious to me.

Comment: you are using the Maclaurin series which is valid for **| x | < 1**. What are the inputs?

Comment: i wanna let the user enters the value of x and n( number of terms)

Comment: Look at your variable `a`.  It's a constant `1`.  You never change it.  Yet you divide by it.  It serves no purpose.   Basically there are no actual divides anywhere in the posted code.  I suggest fixing that bug and trying again.

Comment: @TomKarzes what should i do ?

Comment: @loryyyn Make your code match the formula at the top of your post.  Right now it's not even close.  For example, you're doing things with `(1 - x)`.  That doesn't appear anywhere in the summation.  Get rid of it.  And you need to divide by 1, then 2, then 3, etc.  So create a counter and use that for your division.  Etc. etc.  As I said, not even close.  This is very simple and should be completely mechanical.  Each loop iteration needs to add a term.  You need a power of `x` and a value to divide by.  Sum them up, then negate the result.

Comment: Never describe a problem merely as “it does not work.” Normally, the process at this point would be that you edit the question to give an exact copy of input that reproduces the problem, an exact copy of the output the program produces, an example of the output you want the program to produce instead and, if not obvious, an explanation of the difference between the observed output and the desired output. However, as a major bug in your program has been pointed out, you should fix that. Rewrite your code as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation of the algorithm makes no sense. Below is a correct implementation to compute that sum:

```
float /* or better, double */ x, ln = 0, xn = 1;
/* ... */
if (x >= 1 || x < -1) { /* print error message and exit */ }
for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
    xn *= x;
    ln -= xn / i;
}

/* ... */
```

Comment: UV but better to validate the input `if(fabs(x) >= 1) /* error */`

Comment: @WeatherVane Actually the range check should have been something like `if (x >= 1 || x < -1) /* error */` because the sum should converge (though very slowly) for `x=-1`. I just wanted to focus on the core problem of the OP.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin: `x` = 1 should be allowed too. The series does not converge for `x` = 1, but that is the right answer (ln (1-1) is −∞). 

Comment: Still, you could give a nod to someone who upvoted a terse answer with a suggested improvement, than an "actually" put down.